# Clarification on spring security management of authenticated sessions

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I follow-up my previous question with a different and more specific doubt, consider the following scenario:

- I am currently running an Oauth2 resource server using spring security 6. The client app sends a JWT token with some claims that gets correctly validated by my server.
- At this point, spring security should open a session (or use an existing one) and store the authentication info in the session cookie
- All subsequent requests from that specific client application should now be authenticated, without repeating the JWT validation, until the session expires

However, this does not seem to be the case, as the requests that contain the session header but do not bear the JWT are unhautorized, this is my filter chain:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain oauth2Chain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            // persist authentication
            // // session creation policy
            // .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer ->
            // httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer
            // .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_NEEDED))
            // persist context
            .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
                    .securityContextRepository(new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()))
            // default policy: jwt oauth2 on all requests
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    return http.build();
}
```

I also tried the default first:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    return http.build();
}
```

What is the correct way to make the client authenticate only once per session? Should I explicitly create the session at some point? I only have:

```
@EnableSpringHttpSession
@Configuration
public class HtmlSessionConfig {
    @Bean
    public MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        return new MapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only two sessions are used for a user in an OAuth2 system:

- on the authorization server
- on the client (some server-side state is necessary during the authorization code flow to store some verifiers like nonce or PKCE token if used, and after the flow completed, to store tokens)

But on resource servers, the "state" is sent by the client with each request (token claims). So, **it is the expected behavior that an access token is sent with each request to a resource server and that this resource server validates it for each request** (decodes and validates a JWT or introspect any kind of token).

Comment: Then what you want is not an `oauth2ResourceServer`. You may even not want OAuth2 at all (or just a client which already works with sessions, but in this scenario, tokens will never be used, which makes me write that OAuth2 is probably not what you want).

Comment: And by the way, token introspection is expensive (it is a network call to another service), but JWT validation isn't. The additional latency for validating a JWT and building a security context out of it is negligible compared to building a security context out of a session cookie. If your concern is about API response time, you'd probably get better results spending this time on database and network accesses.

Comment: So basically, if I'm caching the auth server signature, it is faster to revalidate the JWT than it is to check for an authenticated session cookie via spring security?

Comment: You don't cache the authorization server public key yourself, Spri'g does it for you, as well as fetching the new one when it rotates, (and it most probably does.)

Comment: I didn't write that decoding a. JWT is faster than reading a cookie, I wrote that building a security context from a JWT is not longer enough for you to make a difference with a security context restored from a cookie.

Comment: The difference that you can feel between stateful (session based client) and stateless (token based resource server) is in a multi node environment (high availability or horizontal scaling) : you'll have to either share the session between the instances of a given stateful app or use a smart proxy to route all requests with a given session ID to the same instance. This is quite some burden (and probably a little slower than decoding a JWT)